# Can I install SharePoint on Workflow manager server if it required?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, 2019, workflow-manager

Hi I want to prepare a SharePoint 2016 Intranet farm with Workflow manager, Now I have 2 Servers, and I have plan to use one for SharePoint 2016 and Second for Workflow manager.
My question is later can I install SharePoint on Second workflow manager server if it required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Workflow Manager can be deployed as a part of a SharePoint farm or as a separate farm.

**In your case, you should think about 2 things:**

1. Performance.

   - If you are thinking about performance, so I would recommend installing it on a separate farm, and no need to install sharepoint on this server.
2. High availability.

   - If you are thinking about SharePoint farm High availability, so I would recommend installing SharePoint on both servers, then install the workflow manager as a part of this farm.

> **Note:** the supported Workflow Manager topology consists of 1 server or 3 servers for high availability. (***No need to install SharePoint on WF farm***)

**To install WF manager, Check the detailed steps at**

- [Install and Configure Workflow Manager SharePoint 2016 Step By Step](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/configure-workflow-manager-sharepoint-2016/)
- [Configure Workflow Manager for SharePoint 2013.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 2):

Workflow manager can be installed on the same server as SharePoint or on a dedicated server:

[Install and configure workflow for SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/SharePoint/governance/install-and-configure-workflow-for-sharepoint-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN#install-workflow-manager)